# using normal primary key auto-increment or composite key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, primary-key, composite-primary-key

for **mysql** and **inoDB** engine and tables that most use **for read**(not much create and edit compare with read queries)

tables are for blogging platform(user can create blog for themselves) and here are my two option for table schema:

for example for table posts:

> 1: posts(id, blog_id, title, content) => *id is the **only primary key auto
>   increment***
>
> 2: posts(id, blog_id, title, content) => **composite primary key** is
>   (id, blog_id) and I use trigger before create query to increment id
>   column

and in most of my queries there is two type of where:

1: for retrieve a single post:

> `where id=5` for solution one
>
> `where id=2 and blog_id=3` for solution two

2: for retrieve multi posts of single blog

> `where blog_id=3` for solution one
>
> `where blog_id=3` for solution two

**question:** which one is better for performance?

ps. if my question is not clear tell then I explain more.

Comment: I would guess it depends no what your selects look like.

Comment: @JonStirling I edit question

Answer (score 1):

In short, performance-wise it does not matter. With most commonly used DBMS's and in most scenario's you won't see much difference between the two.

However, the most important thing to consider, is a simple one: compatibility and ease of use. Most ORM systems and frameworks are tuned to work with one column being the PK. So if you choose a composite key, it will always require a bit of tuning. Secondly, if you're going for a REST approach in your web application, working with singular ID's makes your life easier as well.

Answer (score 1):

If using a PK of "id, blog_id" : then the leading column in your index is "id".

If your query is "where blog_id = 3" - this *will not* use the index , and will be slow , because blog_id is not the leading column.

Since ID is a unique value within the table - just have it as the PK. Otherwise its misleading, someone may think ID is *not* unique.

If your queries will often use "blog_id" as the criteria, then have a secondary index on that column.

Auto-increment "id" column is better than having a database-trigger in my view. Its fewer moving parts, and lesser amount of code to write.